# Изменить значение в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

имеется массив с содержимым

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => test
            [money] => 100000
            [date] => 15.9.2018, 09:47:01
        )
)
```

как изменить значение в `money`?

Comment: `$array[1]['money'] = 123;`

Comment: @Manitikyl , у меня так массив стирается. (
    [337848488] => Array
        (
            [name] =>
            [money] => 240
            [date] =>
        )

Comment: Не обманывайте нас. Таким образом массив нельзя стереть.